# Why does this compound command report errors when copying directories?

Tags: bash, command-line, command

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this compound command report errors when copying directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43636/why-does-this-compound-command-report-errors-when-copying-directories)

if one executes the following two commands in one line, as follows,

> rm -rf dir ; cp -r dir2 dir

it may complain that cp can not create directory `dir/subdir`: File exists

but if these two commands are executed in two lines, no errors will be thrown. I am just wandering what is the difference? and more importantly, how to execute two commands in one line, with the effect exactly the same as by two lines...

PS: what is in `dir` or `dir2` is hugh, typically 4gb

Answer (score 0):

You can use '&&' to concatenate commands. It runs the next command if the first was succesful.

`rm -rf dir && cp -r dir2 dir`