# Why does this compound command report errors when copying directories?

Tags: bash, shell, command

If one executes the following two commands in one line as follows,

`rm -rf dir ; cp -r dir2 dir`

it may return that cp can not create directory `dir/subdir`: File exists

but if these two commands are executed in two lines, no errors will be thrown. I am just wondering what is the difference and more importantly, how to execute two commands in one line, with the effect exactly the same as by two lines...

EDIT: I change it to `cp -r dir2 dir`. Besides, what is in `dir` or `dir2` is huge, typically 4gb.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the command line you posted. Check to see if either command is aliased or redefined as a function: `type -a rm cp`.

Comment: ``type -a rm cp`` shows ``rm`` is redirected to ``rm -i``, so if ``cp``

Comment: On my system, it gives a different error: ```cp: omitting directory `dir2'``` even when rm is not aliased. So, there's definitely *something* going on, but see solution below.

Comment: By "redirected" I assume you mean aliased. The `-i` option shouldn't cause the problem you're seeing. Is dir2 a symlink? That shouldn't matter, though.

Comment: Is `dir` on an NFS mount, by any chance? I'm picturing the NFS client issuing the `cp` request before the NFS server has finished deleting `dir`. No idea if that's plausible.

Comment: ``dir`` is local ...

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution Without Explanation

I'm not 100% sure *why* this happens, although I suspect it has something to do with how or when Bash is expanding the arguments to *cp*. However, it's easy enough to fix: just add the -a flag. For example:

```
rm -rf dir; cp -a dir2 dir
```

This performs properly on my system, and reports no errors. As proof:

```
$ set -x; rm -rf dir; cp -a dir2 dir; ls
+ rm -rf dir
+ cp -a dir2 dir
dir  dir2
```

Comment: Do you get an error without `-a`? What happens if you use `-d` instead? Is dir2 a symlink?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Yes. On my system, it gives a different error: ```cp: omitting directory `dir2'``` even when rm is hashed to /bin/rm. Ubuntu 11.10, Bash 4.2.10(1)-release. The -d flag gives the same error, as it should, since I'm testing with real directories. The -a flag definitely fixes it, though.